# How do i get the activity?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am requesting permission during run-time, and for the method `requestPermissions()` I need to pass through an activity. However, when I call it in `onClick()` I cannot just pass through `this`. So, how do I pass it through?

The place where I need the activity is in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` , in `case locationPerm:`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    final int locationPerm = 0;
    final int cameraPerm = 1;

    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_nav_bar);

        context = this;


        int locationPermissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        int cameraPermissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        if (locationPermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, locationPerm);
        }

        if (cameraPermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, cameraPerm);
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case locationPerm: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                } else { // permission denied,
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Location Permission")
                            .setMessage("Message")
                            .setPositiveButton("Set a custom location later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(/* NEED ACTIVITY HERE */, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, locationPerm);
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Re-Prompt Request", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case cameraPerm: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                } else { // permission denied,

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry if this is a simple fix, I am fairly new to Android App Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is "this" refers to the Button here.
In order to pass the activity there are two ways:

- `LoginActivity.this` [For sure]
- `getApplicationcontext()` [In case to pass the application context]

Comment: `LoginActivity.this` was the correct solution. `getApplicationContext()` does not work because `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` requires an `Activity` not a `Context`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!